# ¿Como puedo invocar "invalid-feedback" personalizado?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente codigo HTML

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="ddlColonia" class="mb-2">Colonia</label>
    <select id="ddlColonia" class="form-control" required></select>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Correcto!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Falta!</div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de presionar clic en un button, si el control SELECT no tiene ni un solo elemento OPTION entonces lo pase como valido (valid-feedback) pero si tiene al menos un OPTION entonces lo marque como invalido (invalid-feedback) si no selecciona ningun elemento.

Nota: Cuando este control SELECT tenga elementos (este control se llena con un onblur de un input:text), el primero de ellos siempre será un option así:

```
<option val="">--- Seleccione ---</option>
```

El resto de los options tendrán información como esta:

```
<option val="1">Colonia Centro</option>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: hola te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: Puedes dar una mejor explicacion, veo tres cosas diferentes: 1) que el select esta vacio pero siempre existira el `Seleccione` aqui la condicion es == 1 sacar el valid.

Comment: 2) que el select tenga contenido como Colonia Centro y el usuario no haya piqueado nada sacar un invalid. 3) si pickeo algo sacar el valid.

Comment: necesito que muestres un ejemplo del onblur funcionando para poder darte lo que hace falta ...

Answer (score 0):

Usando bootstrap 5 hay una opción de validación para los selectores `<select>` que puedes ver en el [tutorial de bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/validation/#custom-styles) (esta en ingles pero puedes traducirlo al español)

Para esto la primera opción debe tener atributos `selected disabled value=""`...

Tambien no es muy bueno utilizar el atributo `val` en vez de `value`

Aquí esta el código correcto:

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(() => {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Lista:</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="validationCustom04" required>
          <option selected disabled value="">--- Seleccione ---</option>
          <option value="1">Colonia Centro</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
         Por favor seleccione algo
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Continuar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```